# Is it ok to return a positive number of rows and zero columns in QAbstractItemModel?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qabstractitemmodel

I have a `QAbstractItemModel` with multiple rows and 0 columns.
We started using the `ModelTest` class and it breaks on this model. [ModelTest documentation](https://wiki.qt.io/Model_Test) states:

> Some of the conditions caught include:
>
> - hasChildren() returns true if rowCount() is greater then zero.

Here is the implementation of `has_children` in Qt 5.11:

```
bool QAbstractItemModel::hasChildren(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return (rowCount(parent) > 0) && (columnCount(parent) > 0);
}
```

From this implementation, we can deduce that if `rowCount` returns a greater than zero value, `ModelTest` expects `columnCount` to return a greater than zero value too.

On the other hand :

- It looks like it works correctly when `ModelTest` is not involved.
- It is not documented in [hasChildren](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#hasChildren)
- It is not documented in [rowCount](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowCount)
- It is not documented in [columnCount](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#columnCount)
- It prevents [beginRemoveColumn](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginRemoveColumns) / [endRemoveColumns](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#endRemoveColumns) from removing the last column (when there are a greater than zero number of rows). But I guess the model could be reset in this situation though.

So in the end which is it:

- Is `ModelTest` too picky ?
- Am I breaking some contract that I am unaware of ?

Comment: What is the use case for a model with 0 columns? (It sounds empty - somehow.) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff I have a table with user defined content. There is no real use case for zero column, but I do not want my application to crash if the user removes the last one (say if he wants to remove everything and start from zero)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModelTest` is simply designed to test for general pitfalls. If the test fails, that means you have done something inconventional that might or might not be problematic, depending on how the model is used.

It is true that the `ModelTest` is slightly more strict as the rules of the documentation because models are used widely and can for example be passed to custom proxy models or view implementations. So these checks are in place to prevent you from doing something illogical that might break some implementation.

So as long as you test this and it works with the views you use it in, it is not wrong, but it might crash in any future version of Qt or if it is used with custom proxies/views.

My recommendation would be to honor the test and reimplement the `hasChildren` method to behave as expected, simply to avoid problems in the future. After all, even if the rows have no columns, they still exists, so the index does have children - these children simply are empty datasets, but they do exist!

This also means that Qt's implementation of the `hasChildren` is "wrong", as they should honor this stuff in their own implementations - my guess is that this is simply an oversight in their implementation, as they did not consider your use case.

Comment: I tried reimplemented hasChildren, but it failed on another of the ModelTest's assertions. I ended up hiding all the rows when the number of column is zero.